# Is there a way to stop button from being clicked via keyboard?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a button to which I have given the class with CSS:

```
.disabled{
    pointer-events: none ;
    opacity: 0.6 ;
}
```

This means it doesn't get disabled completely. So I can still click it dynamically via javascript.
My problem is that if I use my keyboard and click Tab, I am able to reach the button and on clicking enter it gets clicked.

Is there a way to disable the keyboard-events, or make onfocus events none, through css? So I can just add the class to the button and remove as required, thanks.

Comment: html buttons has disabled attribute. Why don't you use it?

Comment: Try to set `tabindex="-1"` on that button element.

Comment: You mean your reason for not using the `disabled` attribute is that you need to trigger a click event on the element via JS, but `disabled` prevents that from working? Well then remove `disabled` _via JS_ before you trigger the click ...

Comment: @CBroe I don't wish to change the logic that is clicking on this button while it's disabled. I would like some CSS option which would allow me to remove the class further on in the code when required.

Comment: @AtillaArdaAçıkgöz I don't want to use disabled attribute. I have mentioned the reason in the question. It doesn't allow me to click on the button from the backend. And no, I dont want to remove disabled attribute, click on the button and then reinstate disabled. This is not an option.

Comment: May I know the reason for the down votes on the question? I specifically said I don't wish to use the disable attribute. Yet everyone has told me to use it. :(

Answer (score 2):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/pj3heuso/

```js
$('button').click(function(){
   console.log($(this).text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="submit">
Submit 1
</button>

<button type="submit" tabindex="-1">
Submit 2
</button>
```

Second `button` will never get the focus using keyboard because of `tabindex="-1"`

Answer (score 0):

You mean

```js
$(".disabled").prop("disabled",true);

// and/or 

$(".disabled").on("click",function(e) { 
  console.log("clicked"); 
  e.preventDefault() 
});
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Tab to the button" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="disabled">Click</button>
```

Comment: don't want to use disabled property!

Answer (score 0):

You can call your button like this way

`The disabled attribute is a boolean attribute. When present, it specifies that the element should be disabled.A disabled element is unusable.The disabled attribute can be set to keep a user from using the element until some other condition has been met (like selecting a checkbox, etc.). Then, a JavaScript could remove the disabled value, and make the element usable.`

```
<button type="button" class="disabled" disabled>click</button>
```

Try with this snippet

```css
.disabled{
    pointer-events: none ;
    opacity: 0.6 ;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="disabled" disabled>click</button>
```